# Se recarga la pagina cuando uso router-link de vue con laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que contiene un `NavBar` para acceder a las diferentes paginas de mi proyecto. Estoy programando el proyecto usando `Laravel` y `Vue`. El problema que estoy teniendo consiste en que cuando doy click en una de las opciones del `NavBar` me visualiza el componente al cual estoy llamando pero me recarga la pagina. a mi proyecto accedo por la siguiente ruta en el navegador `webDev.acciones.com`

Estos son los archivos de configuracion.

Mi `app.js`

```
    require('./bootstrap');

//import libraries
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

//import Main Component
import App from './components/App.vue';

//import routes

import { routes } from './routes';

const router = new VueRouter(
    {
        mode: 'history', 
        routes
    }
)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    render(h) { return h(App)}
});

routes.js

// Navegation
const Home = () => import ('./components/Home.vue');


// Components VIN
const IndexVin = () => import ('./components/vin/IndexVin.vue');



export const routes = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        path:'/',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        name: 'IndexVin',
        path:'/vins',
        component: IndexVin
    }
]
```

y esto es lo que tengo en mi template:

```
<template>

    <div class="container body">
        <div class="main_container">
            <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
                <div class="left_col scroll-view">

                    <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
                        <a href="#" class="site_title"> <span>VINs</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <br />

                    <!-- sidebar menu -->
                    <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu" >

                        <div class="menu_section">
                            <h3>General</h3>
                            <ul class="nav side-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <router-link :to='{ name: "home"}'><i class="fa fa-cab"></i> Vin list </router-link>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <router-link :to='{ name: "IndexVin"}'><i class="fa fa-cab"></i> New vin </router-link>
                                </li>
                                <!-- <li><router-link :to='{ name: "home"}'><i class="fa fa-cab"></i> Search vin </router-link></li> -->
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /sidebar menu -->

                    <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
                    <div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small pull-right">

                        <a  href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=" Salva Base Datos">
                            <span class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Configuraci&oacute;n General">
                            <span class="fa fa-gears" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Trazas">
                            <span class="fa fa-list-ol" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                        
                    </div>
                    <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="top_nav">
                <div class="nav_menu">
                    <nav class="" role="navigation">
                        <div class="nav toggle">
                            <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                                
                                
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right_col" role="main" id="contenido">
            
            <div id="app">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <router-view></router-view>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            

            <!-- footer content -->

            <footer>
                <div class="copyright-info">
                    <p class="pull-right">VINS - Vehicle Identification Number</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </footer>
            <!-- /footer content -->
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</template>
```

Que pudiera estar sucediendo que me recarga la pagina. Estoy usando `xampp` pero tengo otro proyecto y funciona perfectamente. Alguna idea?